# Finding true height and width of image

Tags: jquery, image, size

This may be a very stupid question. I am having users crop their own photos upon upload with the imgAreaSelect jQuery plugin. As many users have found here, and elsewhere, is that when resizing with CSS the crop is not correctly selected portion. Thankfully, imgAreaSelect can handle this with imageHeight and imageWidth. There was already an answer on here that go me started. Sadly I was unable to comment there just yet.

My problem is finding the true height and width of the attached image. I've tried various ways of getting it but each time console output is undefined for originalHeight/originalWidth as shown below.

The first, which was a solution found on here, was:

```
var imageSize = $("#uploadImage");

var originalHeight = imageSize.naturalHeight;
var originalWidth = imageSize.naturalWidth;
```

The second was with this.width/this.height which was found here: stackoverflow.com/questions/318630:

```
var imageSize = $("uploadImage")[0]; 
var originalWidth, originalHeight;
$("<img/>") 
    .attr("src", $(imageSize).attr("src"))
    .load(function() {
        originalWidth = this.width;  
        originalHeight = this.height; 
    });
```

I'm placing my full code below because I may just completely missed something as I'm clearly a beginner. The image is showing in preview and cropping, just not properly.

```
function getCoordinates(img, selection) {
    var porcX = img.naturalWidth / img.width;
    var porcY = img.naturalHeight / img.height;

    $('#x1').val(Math.round(selection.x1 * porcX));
    $('#y1').val(Math.round(selection.y1 * porcY));
    $('#x2').val(Math.round(selection.x2 * porcX));
    $('#y2').val(Math.round(selection.y2 * porcY));
    $('#w').val(Math.round(selection.width * porcX));
    $('#h').val(Math.round(selection.height * porcY));
}

$(document).ready(function() {

    var preview = $("#uploadPreview");

    $("#uploadImage").change(function(){

        preview.fadeOut();

        var oFReader = new FileReader();
        oFReader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("uploadImage").files[0]);

        oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent) {
            preview.attr('src', oFREvent.target.result).fadeIn();
        };
    });

    var imageSize = $("#uploadImage");

    var originalHeight = imageSize.naturalHeight;
    var originalWidth = imageSize.naturalWidth;

    $('#uploadPreview').imgAreaSelect({
        aspectRatio: '24:29',
        handles: true,
        fadeSpeed: 200,
        imageHeight: originalHeight, 
        imageWidth: originalWidth,
        onSelectChange: getCoordinates 
    });

});
```

Comment: You may want to replace `$(document).ready(function() {` with `$(window).load(function() {`

Comment: Thanks for your reply @user3558931. same result though. The ready/load wouldn't have an impact on sourcing the images width/height. at least i wouldn't think so

Comment: Which is which? Same result or you don't think so?

Comment: It looks like it's just imgAreaSelect and max-width. Doesn't look like this will work unless I resize the image first.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    var img = $("img")[0]; // Get my img elem
    var pic_real_width, pic_real_height;
    $("<img/>") // Make in memory copy of image to avoid css issues
    .attr("src", $(img).attr("src"))
    .load(function() {
        pic_real_width = this.width;   // Note: $(this).width() will not
        pic_real_height = this.height; // work for in memory images.
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I did try that one, but same result

Comment: did you test it in different browsers? IE,Chrome, FF, same result?

Comment: Yes, the final image is consistently off in all modern browsers